# How to add a link on a ui_component button?

Tags: magento2

I am learning how to use the Magento 2 UI_Compoenent and I have a question. I noticed there are 2 ways to add 1 button to magento:

1° `<button name="back" class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton"/>`

2°

```
<buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true"> back </label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
```

In the second form inside url = "" I can specify a route and the controller and it will perform an action, but what about the first form? How would I do this? Which would be the most attributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you mentioned in first point is used uicomponent xml files. If you follow `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton` you'll see it has `getButtonData` method that comes from `ButtonProviderInterface`.

If you add `url` to the array you'll be able to use same url attribute in the  second point.

For this particular case it has `on_click` event so it may not be good idea to give url to this particular component.

```
/**
* \Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Edit\BackButton
*/
...
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'url' => "/*/*", // make sure you remove onclick up there.
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }
...
```

Comment: and which of the 2 would be the best to use in a ui component?

Comment: You don't really have to use Block class if you don't need that url specifically generated by php code. So second option is pretty useful and easy if you just want it to be redirected to related controller.

Answer (score 1):

**This Way is best for add a button in the UI component. We can assign URL and also add parameters and also you put logic when URL and params are dynamic.**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        ............................................................................................................
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
        </item>
        ............................................................................................................
    </argument>
    ................................................................................................................
</form>
```

> *There are many types of buttons In the Form like Save, Edit, Back, Delete, New, etc. In developing the module we need to add a button to the form. Here is some code to add different buttons to the form.*

**Step-1: Create Generic.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Generic
{
    protected $context;
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Step-2: Create Back.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Back extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10,
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**Step-3: Create Reset.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Reset implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Reset'),
            'class' => 'reset',
            'on_click' => 'location.reload();',
            'sort_order' => 30,
        ];
    }
}
```

**Step-4: Create Delete.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Buttons**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;
 
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
 
class Delete extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected $context;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }
 
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }
 
    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but why are the buttons in BLock instead of the controller? o.O

Comment: From this Block, we build buttons and define button action. Action must be a controller or any logic of code.